# Log4j 2 not writing logs within a Spring 2.5 Tomcat app

Tags: java, spring, maven, log4j, log4j2

I pulled out an old project based on Spring 2.5 and Log4j 1.2 and started to upgrade it to nowadays library dependencies.

Updating Spring is time expensive, so I started with other libraries and changed from Log4j 1.2 to Log4j 2.

I already fixed all dependency problems using the maven enforcer plugin!

My maven dependencies look like this now:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
  <version>2.11.2</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
  <version>2.11.2</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>log4j-1.2-api</artifactId>
  <version>2.11.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Within my (old) web.xml the following ist still configured:

```
<listener>
  <listener-class>org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<context-param>
  <param-name>log4jConfigLocation</param-name>
  <param-value>classpath:log4j.properties</param-value>
</context-param>
```

So I assumed that everything should work, because of the backward compatibility. But within my Tomcat's logfile only the following appears:

```
04-Apr-2019 12:45:05.035 INFORMATION [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log Initializing log4j from [classpath:log4j.properties]
04-Apr-2019 12:45:05.068 INFORMATION [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
04-Apr-2019 12:45:17.661 INFORMATION [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'test'
```

and then nothing more ... where thousends of log entries should be ...

I have searched all tomcat logfiles without success - there is no exception and nothing else that gives me a hint why my code will not run with Log4j2 - any hints?

When reverting to log4j 1.2 everything works as expected.

Comment: My guess is that you need to update the logging config to be log4j 2.x compatible.  Have you read https://logging.apache.org/log4j/log4j-2.2/manual/migration.html ?

Comment: Yes I have thats why I am using the bridge.

Comment: I have also convertd the logging config and changed the web.xml to point to log4j2.properties without success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the end it was quite simple:

I had copied the dependencies (api, core) from mvnrepository.com so that they contain:

```
<scope>test</scope>
```

which has to be removed - after this I also had to fix a last dependency problem - then the logging was back.

Last but not least it seems that the log4j converter for the properties is not really complete, so I added a log4j2.properties in parallel to get the results for rollingAppender.

Answer (score 0):

Please consider the answer as an attempt to troubleshoot the described situation.
The answer is "common" because too many things can go wrong here, it's very hard to tell without knowing the code and configurations, and reflects how I would have approached this task

The migration log4j 1.x to log4j 2.x is not as easy as just jars switching.
So, first of all, make sure you understand (and apply on your codebase) this [migration guide](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/migration.html) Some imports should be changed.

Then I think you should make sure that log4j 1.x doesn't propagate into the artifact of your application (one possible reason is that its defined as a transitive dependency)

In order to track this, run `mvn dependency:tree` and if there is no log4j 1.x jars - its good.

Now, sometimes (in case of Spring itself for example), libraries, and probably your own code doesn't use log4j loggers directly, and use slf4j instead.
In this case you'll need a binding of slf4j to log4j2: https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/log4j-slf4j-impl/

Then you can start checking the configuration.
The best way is to debug your application that has something like somewhere in the code:

```
 logger.info("Some message");
```

Place a breakpoint there and check what kind of logger do you have and what appenders are really assigned to it, maybe the bridge doesn't work and the application in runtime has a no-op implementation or, if its a real implementation, maybe the appenders are not assigned properly and the message goes nowhere.

Comment: As already written I am using the enforcer plugin - so all dependencies are clean here. Looks like only debugging is left to me ...